# AlarmManager not firing alarm for the next day

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have this alarm manager which I want to fire at 6 AM everyday. I call the class notification, when the app is first launched and hence, it sets an repeating alarm for 6 AM every day(repeatedly).

The alarm manager works fine when the user installs(and runs the app first time) from 6 to 9 AM, however if the user runs the app for the first time after 9 AM, I'm supposed to add a day and fire the alarm the next day at 6AM. On doing so, (changing the date to the next day), the alarm gets fired at a random time, around 10 PM (That's a huge difference). Here's my code"

```
    public notification(Context context) {

    this.context=context;

    Intent appstart=new Intent(context,appstartreceiver.class);
    PendingIntent  pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,appstart,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); // For appstart in the morning
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar currentCal=Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar startapp = Calendar.getInstance();// FOr app start in the morning

    startapp.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,6);
    startapp.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    startapp.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


    long currentTime = currentCal.getTimeInMillis();


    int diff=(int)(currentTime-startapp.getTimeInMillis())/(1000*60*60);

    if (diff<3)
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,startapp.getTimeInMillis(),1000*24*60*60,pi);
    else {

        startapp.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);


        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startapp.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60, pi);
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't get your else part. If you want to set repeating alarm everyday at 6 am then alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,startapp.getTimeInMillis(),1000*24*60*60,pi); is enough.

Comment: On doing that, when the user installs the app at say 1 PM, android schedules the alarm for the next day at 1 PM and not 6! That's problematic!

Comment: No it will fire at 6 o clock only... I think you tested like this...after running the app at 1 pm then you changed the date of the device to next day then your alarm is fired at that time...is it right??

Comment: To be exact, I installed the app at 1 PM. Changed the date of the device to the next day at 5 Am waited a minute, then to 6 AM, to 7AM, and SO ON finally to 1 PM! That was the only time the notification appeared

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with below code...this will fire everyday at 6 am. It may helps you.

```
public void notification(Context context) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, appstartreceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 99, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    long startUpTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    // To avoid firing the alarm if the time is passed while setting
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > startUpTime) {
        startUpTime = startUpTime + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    }

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startUpTime, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried the code and it gives me the same problem as before. I should probably try it on a different phone or in the emulator. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a day

`if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
       calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
   }
  ....// your code`

That way it will fire everyday at the set time.

Answer (score 0):

Try commonwares's wakeful intent service,it may help.

```
public class DailyListener implements AlarmListener {
    public void scheduleAlarms(AlarmManager mgr, PendingIntent pi, Context context) {

            // every day at scheduled time 
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
           // if it's after or equal 6 am schedule for next day
           if (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 6) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); 
            }
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

      mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);


    }
}
```